# React counter does not increment when taking the number from an input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, counter, ref

React counter the "+" and "-" buttons does not increment when taking the number from an input it just adds 1111111 but decrement normally.
also the "+" and "-" buttons work normally if user didn't insert number from input.
here is my code :

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  var [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  function handleClick() {
    setCount(inputRef.current.value);
  }

  function decrease() {
    setCount(count - 1);
  }
  function increase() {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <input ref={inputRef} type="text" id="message" name="message"></input>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Enter</button>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
      <button onClick={increase}>+</button>

    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: use input type="number"  instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `inputRef.current.value` is a string and this means `+` will be a concatenation operation between a string and a number. JavaScript will therefore cast the number to string in `decrease()` and `increase()` functions, thus resulting in an output like `111..`.

To fix this, please cast the input value to a number:

```js
var [count, setCount] = useState(0);
function handleClick() {
  setCount(+inputRef.current.value);
}
```

Notice the `+` operator, this will convert the input value to a number. If you want to parse to an integer or a float, you may want to use `parseInt(inputRef.current.value)` or `parseFloat(inputRef.current.value)` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
function handleClick() {
 setCount(parseInt(inputRef.current.value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you type in the input is type of `string`, so you need to parse it to an integer.

Try like this:

```js
function App() {
  var [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  function handleClick() {
    setCount(parseInt(inputRef.current.value));
  }

  function decrease() {
    setCount(count - 1);
  }
  function increase() {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <input ref={inputRef} type="text" id="message" name="message"></input>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Enter</button>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={decrease}>-</button>
      <button onClick={increase}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value from `input` is a string. Try converting it to number

```js
function handleClick() {
    setCount(Number(inputRef.current.value));
  }
```